# Overriding method must be marked with 'override' or 'final' with clang++

Tags: c++, boost, clang, clang++, llvm-clang

I am compiling a project using clang++. In this project I am including a boost library file: `exceptions.hpp`

When I am compiling this project it gives an error:

> /home/builder/base/packages/al/boost_1_66_0/boost/interprocess/exceptions.hpp:63:45:
>   error: [chromium-style] Overriding method must be marked with
>   'override' or 'final'

Please suggest any solution.

Comment: The error message is pretty self explanatory, just add the `override` keyword to the overriding function.

Comment: Thanks Jesper ! I am using boost library and the problem is that I don't want to make change in any boost library file. There are several other boost header files which is showing the same error.

Comment: The problem might be the location of your `boost` installation.  Try adding `-isystem /home/builder/base/packages/al/boost_1_66_0` to your compilation flags to suppress the warning.

Comment: Thanks GM, you really helped me ...it solved my problem..thanks again.